# Incorrect conditional probability when expanding expression (bayes theorem)

Tags: conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Given the following probabilities:

$P(A) = 0.5$, $P(¬A) = 0.5$

$P(E|A) = 0.1$, $P(F|A) = 0.8$

$P(E|¬A) = 0.3$, $P(F|¬A) = 0.2$

I am trying to solve for $P(A|Z)$ where $Z = (E ∩ F)$. Please note that **conditional independence applies** here.

I've successfully found an answer by not expanding Z to it's whole form, i.e.

$P(A|Z) = \frac{P(A)P(Z|A)}{P(Z)}$ [bayes theorem]

$P(A|Z) = \frac{P(A)P(E ∩ F|A)}{P(Z)}$ [expand numerator]

$P(A|Z) = \frac{P(A)P(E|A)P(F|A)}{P(Z)}$

Apply $P(Z) = P(A)P(Z|A)+P(¬A)P(Z|¬A)$ to denominator:

$P(A|Z) = \frac{P(A)P(E|A)P(F|A)}{P(A)P(Z|A)+P(¬A)P(Z|¬A)}$

$P(A|Z) = \frac{P(A)P(E|A)P(F|A)}{P(A)P(E ∩ F|A)+P(¬A)P(E ∩ F|¬A)}$ [expand denominator]

$P(A|Z) = \frac{P(A)P(E|A)P(F|A)}{P(A)P(E|A)(F|A)+P(¬A)P(E|¬A)P(F|¬A)}$ [final expression]

---

Now, if I start again by expanding Z before applying $P(Z) = P(A)P(Z|A)+P(¬A)P(Z|¬A)$.

$P(A|Z) = \frac{P(A)P(E|A)P(F|A)}{P(E ∩ F)}$

And apply conditional independence $P(E ∩ F) = P(E)*P(F|E) = P(E)P(F)$:

$P(A|Z) = \frac{P(A)P(E|A)P(F|A)}{P(E)P(F)}$

and apply $P(E) = P(E|A)P(A) + P(E|¬A)P(¬A)$ (apply to $P(F)$ as well):

$P(A|Z) = \frac{P(A)P(E|A)P(F|A)}{[P(E|A)P(A) + P(E|¬A)P(¬A)][P(F|A)P(A) + P(F|¬A)P(¬A)]}$ [final expression]

---

Solving each of these final expressions using the given probabilities, I get two different answers:

$\frac{0.5*0.1*0.8}{0.5*0.1*0.8+0.5*0.3*0.2}$ = $P(A|E,F) = 0.57$

$\frac{0.5*0.1*0.8}{[0.1*0.5 + 0.3*0.5][0.8*0.5 + 0.2*0.5]} = P(A|E,F) = 0.40$

Any help on where I went wrong in my expansion/understanding would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Bayes Theorem is correct, it seems your assumptions are wrong. What are you assuming really? Are $E$ and $F$ independent? Are they also independent given $A$?

Comment: @WilliamM. E and F are independent, and they are also independent given A. The context of the question is that I am trying to find the probability of a message being from "Jane", where A is "Jane" and ¬ is another person "John" (the class variable), given that E and F exist in a message. E and F represent individual words existing in a message (i.e. E="black" and F="gold"). E and F are independent because a message could include either/both. And they are both independent given A because X or Y could write a message including or not including either word.

Comment: The context is irrelevant, it seems to me that this is an illegal assignation of probabilities or that some things you are using are not true. For example, $E$ and $F$ need not be independent given $¬A.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming $E$ and $F$ independent and also independent given $A.$ Then,
$$
P(E) = P(E \mid A) P(A) + P(E \mid ¬A)P(¬A) = (0.1)(0.5)+(0.3)(0.5) = 0.2,
$$
similarly
$$
P(F) = 0.5
$$
This gives $P(EF) = (0.2)(0.5) = 0.1.$ And the assumption gives $P(EF \mid A) = (0.1)(0.8) = 0.08.$ Then
$$
\begin{align*}
P(EF \mid ¬A) &= 2 P(EF¬A) = 2(P(EF) - P(EFA)) \\
&= 2(P(EF)-P(E\mid A)P(F \mid A) P(A)) = 2((0.1) - (0.1)(0.8)(0.5)) \\
&= 0.12 \neq P(E \mid ¬A) P(F \mid ¬A).
\end{align*}
$$

So $E$ and $F$ aren't independent given $¬A,$ which is one thing you are assuming as well. I didn't check other things. At any rate, you cannot apply several steps you did apply.

Comment: Ah, I found my mistake. I assumed that $P(E ∩ F) = P(E)P(F|E) = P(E)P(F)$, but it is not the case that $P(F|E) = P(F)$. There must be dependence here. Can we rewrite the denominator $P(E ∩ F)$ then as $P(E ∩ F | A) + P(E ∩ F | ¬A)$?

Comment: No, @AdamFrank . By the Law of Total Probability we have: $$\mathsf P(E\cap F)=\mathsf P(E\cap F\mid A)\,\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(E\cap F\mid\lnot A)\,\mathsf P(\lnot A)$$

Comment: Oops, yes I left the $P(A)$ and $P(¬A)$ part out. Which thus the statement does end up producing the same answer. Thanks for the help everyone!